# Getting a user's Paypal subscription details

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I would like people to be able to subscribe to my website through Paypal. I've managed to install the Paypal buttons and can now obtain an access token to make "REST API" calls. But I'm failing to get any details of the subscriptions. Here's my cURL code which I run through reqbin.com:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans?page_size=3&status=ALL&page_size=2&page=1&total_required=yes \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAOtUj14g7QOd..............mL2MjJrgPE-Hr5lkaBN4f5Tg8wiErwgWd-sn-1hg6yqRMjtgRg"

curl -v -X GET https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-8YD8773..........5UOKQ \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAOtUj14g7QOdj2PKN............6nutDPKmL2MjJrgPE-Hr5lkaBN4f5Tg8wiErwgWd-sn-1hg6yqRMjtgRg"
```

where you can see I have inserted the details of my access token and my billing plan ID obtained from my Paypal account. The former curl call should return details of my billing plan ID and the latter subscriptions under it. But the billing plan doesn't seem to exist as far as the API-REST goes. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe posting Authorization headers on the internet is not best thing to do.

Comment: That's why I substituted much of the middle with dots.

Comment: Sorry about that. Was on my phone and did not notice the dots but wanted to let you know in case you posted it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a deprecated [billing-plans API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/).

The current PayPal Subscriptions APIs are documented [here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/), with a guide [here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/)

Comment: Not sure about it being deprecated, because I got the code from the location that you have linked to. But I think I had failed to understand that a billing plan is not the same as a subscription plan. It seems to be working OK now, thanks.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/ says it is deprecated ...